# How to avoid circular dependency while adding references to windows runtimecomponent?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, background-task

I added a windows store Blank App,named app, and a windows RTComponent, named backgroundtask, to my project solution. So, I had to add to add references to `backgroundtask` in app.

But I also needed to use the data input in the `app` in `Backgroundtask`. So, I created a class in `app` and tried to add references to `app` in `Backgroundtask`.

It displayed an error stating circular dependency. How can I use the data fed to `app` through `Backgroundtask` and add references to `Backgroundtask` through `app` all at the same time?

Comment: I would think the app would need to bind to a (view)model that is declared in the background task component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why `Backgroundtask` needs to reference `app`, unless

- you're trying to access public static variables from the other project, or
- you're passing an instance of a class from the `app` project, so `Backgroundtask` can't access it

Instead, pass the values from `app` as parameters to whatever method you're calling in `Backgroundtask` or, if there are a lot of values to pass, create a third project which contains the classes that need to be shared between both projects.

- Create a project called `Shared` and reference it from both of the other projects.
- Add a new class called `AppData` (or name it something more specific that seems appropriate).
- Instantiate the class in `app`, populate it with the data you need, and pass it to a method in `Backgroundtask` that accepts a parameter of that class type.

Either one of those options should eliminate the need for a circular dependency.

Comment: I created project named `Shared`,which is also a blank app(XAML) containing a class(class1 which has a lot of values to pass and I made them public static variables). I intended to access those data items via `app` but I get an error displaying: Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'MainPage.xbf'.How can I solve it?